# Passing arguments to a function?

Tags: javascript

I need to learn how to pass an associative array to a function so that I could do the following within the function:

```
function someName($argums) {
    if (gettype($argums) != 'array' || 
       !array_key_exists('myOneKey', $argums) ||
       !array_key_exists('myOtherKey', $argums)) {              
           return false;
    } 

    /*do other stuff*/
}
```

(That's how I would do it in PHP that I am looking for in JavaScript.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Javascript objects are associative arrays, so this is really easy. You actually have a few options, because an object can have properties of its own, properties it inherits from its prototype object, properties with undefined values, and properties with "falsey" values (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, or of course, `false`). (There's a difference between an object *not having* a property and having one with an undefined value.)

Checking to see if the object has the properties itself: You use `obj.hasOwnProperty`:

```
function someName(obj) {
    if (!obj ||
        !obj.hasOwnProperty('myOneKey') ||
        !obj.hasOwnProperty('myOtherKey'))
        return false;
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Checking to see if the object has the property itself *or* via its prototype: You use `propName in obj`:

```
function someName(obj) {
    if (!obj ||
        !('myOneKey' in obj) ||
        !('myOtherKey' in obj))
        return false;
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Checking to see if the object has the property (directly, or via prototype) and it's not undefined: You look for an undefined value:

```
function someName(obj) {
    if (!obj ||
        typeof obj.myOneKey === "undefined" ||
        typeof obj.myOtherKey === "undefined")
        return false;
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Checking to see if the property is falsey (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, or of course, `false`), regardless of why: Just use `!`:

```
function someName(obj) {
    if (!obj ||
        !obj.myOneKey ||
        !obj.myOtherKey)
        return false;
    }
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Regardless, usage:

```
var obj = {
    myOneKey: 'fred',
    myOtherKey: 'barney'
};
someName(obj);
```

Comment: And how would I call that function with such arguments?

Comment: And can't I use the in operator instead of hasOwnProperty?

Comment: @dfjhdfjhdf: I was adding a discussion of that and the distinction between them as you were asking the question, apparently. :-)

Comment: +1 - Great answer for including all the FAQs that come along with this